# Can't update subdocuments with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm having problems when I try to update data from a subdocument with mongoose

here is the data model:

```
{ status: 'regular',
  devices:
   [ { ip: 'deviceIp',
       active: true,
       _id: 5f4c05cb4708cf0e37a68ac0,
       name: 'deviceName',
       os: 'deviceOs',
       refreshToken:
        'eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.eyJ1c2VyIjoidGVzdFVzZXIiLCJtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB1c2VyLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTU5ODgxNzczOSwibmJmIjoxNTk4ODE3NzQxLCJleHAiOjE2MDE0MDk3MzksImF1ZCI6Im15YXVkIiwiaXNzIjoibXlpc3N1ZXIiLCJzdWIiOiJ2IiwianRpIjoiMSJ9.di6BeKZV5OufLEY8Hnk_nC_vcCsVZZ_XJecUc1h695hDbFlgxTtNOZoi-e3uvAkckclfAKjJk7T-osEGohsnfpdA07XDH3pOniGYHVw_k1u-e6-0pu9YpSop6cv7cnlsR-50QjE9vmzg4F1mBy2ZYVCp6GSfg46duXjStUOamUM30AYElSSVX5EMsK1uBg2tfVipV8xRhHCZIIdYNr-xq8G5CcZ1lEIQrtkC2ljU7roLpC5pejZ-JkaHSNNKwVARW7JuLNbb4FaSAjv_AE87faozPWAbdgXIaap8A5nLeH_-XJhwJDIIRGnwwsJM969DaTVee2F40lUfBzhugmffeg',
       loginDate: 2020-08-30T20:02:19.257Z } ],
  _id: 5f4c05c64708cf0e37a68abf,
  username: 'testUser',
  password: 'Xa8S8qxXsQqAvenX5Kk4BloZfX1XePosVCNXoyLBQz4=',
  mail: 'test@user.com',
  salt: 'hDsCu0CShRbE/XFAvw6y/8SLu4vufP7a7ewiCBLXIQ0=',
  __v: 3 }
```

And here is what I did in TS:

```js
let userQuery = await UserModel.find({

  "devices.refreshToken": refreshToken,
  "devices.active": true

});

let userInfo:any = userQuery[0];

if(!userInfo){

  reject("Invalid token");
  return;

}

let device = userInfo.devices.filter(_device => _device.refreshToken == refreshToken)[0];

userInfo.updateOne( { _id: userInfo._id , "devices._id": device._id},{ $set: {"devices.$.active":false} });
```

Each device was generated like this:

```js
let userDevice = new DeviceModel({

  ...device,
  refreshToken,
  active:true,

});

userInfo.devices.push(userDevice);
```

The problem is that the data inside the devices array never gets updated, even when the query works correctly

Comment: Try logging the values of the arguments being pased to the updateOne call so you can examine that specific query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first to check the query against the mongoDB not in code, using for instance Robo 3T:

For your case try the following:

```
db.getCollection('YOUR COLLECTION NAME HERE').updateOne({ '_id': 5f4c05c64708cf0e37a68abf ,'devices._id': 5f4c05cb4708cf0e37a68ac0 }, { $set: { 'devices.$.active': false }});
```